# HTML font awesome not showing icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have downloaded font awesome min.css and referenced in my HTML markup as below. But the font awesome Icons are not showing up only text "Solution" shows up. Below is my markup.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\CSS\font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
              Solution
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
    </div>
</body>
```

I can see that the font-awesome.min.css file is loaded. But The below property appears striked out (not applied) in browser:-

```
 .fa-lightbulb-o::before {
    content: "\f0eb";
  }
```

Please let me know what's wrong are missing. This is the 1st time I am using it.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure from the css file path?

Comment: You probably want to put `font-awesome.min.css` relative to your URL, such as `css/font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: I just created a folder called CSS in c drive and placed the font-awesome.min.css file there. But I will move it out from there later just trying to understand how to use font-awesome.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/52WdB/

It works fine online, it is because you are referencing your CSS incorrectly.

Use this:

```
href='file:///C:\CSS\font-awesome.min.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this might actually have to do with the way you're calling your stylesheet.

Can you verify that you're actually loading font-awesome? because the way you link to it is telling me that that URL is absolute. And also you should probably use the forward slash, since backslashes are used for the PC's filesystem.

Try this, if your index.html has a 'CSS' folder nested in it:

`<head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>`

Comment: Although I agree that it would be better to store it in a folder along with the html file - sometimes you can't or the workflow is better not to when offline. (See my answer) Online, for example, if you were referencing a file and were using 'http :/ /etc..', but it wasn't working due to incorrect referencing, the answer wouldn't be to 'store it in the same folder'

Comment: Ok I now moved the .css file to web and refrenced as below:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Style%20Library/CSS/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" /> . But still I face the same issue.

Comment: I feel like the issue is still with the linking of the stylesheet. If working offline only isn't a constraint you might consider [hosting a CDN version of Fontawesome](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome) in which the URL you want goes in the 'href' attribute